# PHP MVC Class loaded locally but not when uploaded to host

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller

I have created the MVC directory structure and started with writing an "App" class.
Everything works well on the local machine using WAMP. But it fails when uploaded to the hosting server.

So, I compared PHP settings between host and local, all looks good, everything matches version etc. I checked paths etc.

Here is my PRIVATE directory structure:

[image]

This is the PUBLIC area

[image]

This is the index.php file:

```
<?php

require_once '../httpd.private/init.php';
require_once '../httpd.private/core/App.php';
$app = new App;

?>
```

Which loads the INIT.PHP variables:

```
<?php

    // Define path constants

    define("DS", DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

    define("ROOT", getcwd() . DS);
    define("APP_PATH", ROOT . '../httpd.private' . DS);
    define("VIEW_PATH", ROOT . "views" . DS);
    define("MODEL_PATH", APP_PATH . "models" . DS);
    define("DATA",   APP_PATH  . "data"   . DS);
    define("CORE_PATH", APP_PATH . "core" . DS);
    define("CONTROLLER_PATH", APP_PATH . "controllers" . DS);
    define('SEC_PATH', APP_PATH . "sec" . DS);
    define("UPLOAD_PATH", APP_PATH . "uploads" . DS);
    define('FILE_ENCRYPTION_BLOCKS', 10000);
    

    $modules = [ROOT, APP_PATH, VIEW_PATH, MODEL_PATH, DATA, CORE_PATH, CONTROLLER_PATH, SEC_PATH];

    set_include_path(get_include_path(). PATH_SEPARATOR . implode(PATH_SEPARATOR,$modules));

    spl_autoload_register('spl_autoload', false);

  
?>
```

After the init file the App.php kicks in:

```
<?php

class App
{
    protected $controller = 'homeController';
    protected $method = 'index';
    protected $params = [];
    
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->parseUrl();

        if (file_exists(CONTROLLER_PATH . $this->controller . '.php'))
        {
            $this->controller = new $this->controller;

            if (method_exists($this->controller, $this->method))
            {
                call_user_func_array([$this->controller, $this->method], $this->params);
            } else {

                header("Location: /home/index");
            }

        } else {

            header("Location: /home/index");
        }
        exit();
    }

    public function parseUrl()
    {
        if (isset($_GET['url'])){

            $url = explode('/', filter_var(rtrim($_GET['url'], '/'),  FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));

            $this->controller = isset($url[0]) ? $url[0] . 'Controller' : 'homeController';

            $this->method = isset($url[1]) ? $url[1] :'index';
            unset($url[0], $url[1]);
            $this->params = !empty($url) ? array_values($url) : [];
        }
    }
}
?>
```

The ERROR:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'homeController' not found in
> /customers/2/e/9/something.com/httpd.private/core/App.php:15
> Stack trace: #0 /customers/2/e/9/something.com/httpd.www/index.php(5): App->__construct() #1 {main} thrown in /customers/2/e/9/something.com/httpd.private/core/App.php on line 15

This is line 15 that is mentioned in the error:

```
$this->controller = new $this->controller;
```

And here is the controller.php file:

```
<?php

class Controller
{
    protected $view;
    protected $model;
    
    public function __construct()
    {
/*      echo "This is the Class: " . __CLASS__ . "<br>";
        echo "And this is the Method: " . __METHOD__ . "<br>";
        die(); */
    }

    public function view($viewName, $data = [])
    {
        $this->view = new View($viewName, $data);
        return $this->view; 
    }

    public function model($modelName, $data = [])
    {
        if (file_exists(MODEL_PATH . $modelName . 'Model' . '.php')){
            require MODEL_PATH . $modelName . 'Model' . '.php';
            $this->model = new $modelName;
        }
    }
}

?>
```

How can I correct the error and perhaps better improve the code?

I am aware that I could start with using composer and other frameworks, but that will not help my homework.

Comment: Do you get any error logs?

Comment: Sorry Dieter, I'm afraid not. MY hosting only allows php erros on/off. No logs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any line where you include your controller file.

Before the instantiation of your controller, you need to require the script.

(You have done that with your model)

Comment: Hi Renaud, thank you for the repsonse. Just to check for understanding if you mean that I require the model at this line "
            require MODEL_PATH . $modelName . 'Model' . '.php';". I have put a similar line in the App.php (require CONTROLLER_PATH . $this->$controller . '.php';)  BUT my understanding was that it was not necessary because of the auto loading. It does work on my local system (WAMP) but not whan I upload it.

Comment: Having placed the require statement I am now getting (
/customers/2/e/9/something.com/httpd.www/../httpd.private/controllers/homeController
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Controller' not found in /customers/2/e/9/something.com/httpd.private/controllers/homeController.php:3 ... where line 3 reads "class HomeController extends Controller". Something ois not quite right here.

Comment: Ok, so with this include, it work (you need to include the Controller class has well).

Comment: After some tests using your code, i've seen that the spl_autoload_register('spl_autoload') doesn't work, you need to provide a callback to this function : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php  

Using this autoloader seems to work :

spl_autoload_register(function ($class_name) {
    include $class_name . '.php';
});

Comment: Hi there, YES! ok. It does work. But now as I move from page to page does this mean I have to include all the files for that page. I thought the idea of spl_autoload was that it did  just that AUTOLOAD. And it does son my local system but not when I host it. Any other thoughts? Really appreciate it!

Comment: Sorry for the format of my message, i'm  new here :x
So you need to provide a "valid" autoloader to spl_autoload_register.

I don't know why the default one doesn't load your classes, maybe something wrong with your include path?

Comment: No problem, me I am new here too. Well, I would not have known the answer without you. I tried for 4 days. Locally it works fine so I stayed away from that being the cause.  Like you said it should have worked but then again this is coding, one never knows.  ;)